# VBA - Identifying Format and Using It as Condition

Tags: excel, vba, format

I have a form where users are asked to input information into a field.
The information comes in 1 of 3 formats:
12345-647-91
1234-5678-91
or
12345-6789-1

I am trying to create a macro that identifies the format and based on that outputs a new value. For example

```
  If format = XXXXX-XXX-XX Then
  output XXXXX-0XXX-00XX

  else if format = XXXX-XXXX-XX Then
  output 0XXXX-XXXX-00XX'
```

etc

Any guidance?

Comment: [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) can work here.

Comment: Do you want *all* outputs to be in the format `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX` and add zeros in front of any sets of digits smaller than four? Will these always be numbers or may letters also appear?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, yes a zero will be added in front of any set of digits less than 4.  They will always be numbers.

Comment: @BigBen I am not having luck with Like operator because the input by used always has hyphens as should the output. When using Like the hyphens are giving me issues.

Comment: What should the output of `12345-647-91` be? What happens to the 5th digit?

Comment: @BigBen, I updated the original post. All out puts should be 12345-1234-1234. Adding a 0 to the front of each section to make sure the above pattern is followed

Comment: Then I would tweak @JvDv's answer using `Split` as that is probably the best approach. You can also use `Like` if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) for this:

```
Private Function myFormat(ByVal userInput As String) As String

    If userInput Like "#####-###-##" Then

        myFormat = Mid$(userInput, 1, 6) & "0" & _
                   Mid$(userInput, 7, 4) & "00" & _
                   Mid$(userInput, 8, 2)

    ElseIf userInput Like "####-####-##" Then

        myFormat = Mid$(userInput, 1, 10) & "00" & _
                   Mid$(userInput, 11, 2)

    ElseIf userInput Like "#####-####-#" Then
        ' and so on
    End If

End Function
```

Called like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print myFormat("99999-999-99") '<~ returns 99999-0999-0099
    Debug.Print myFormat("9999-9999-99") '<~ returns 9999-9999-0099
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sure you had to tweak it though, right? Because right now it doesn't add the leading zero in the case of ###-###-##. Though that's an easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array("12345-123-12", "1234-1234-12", "12345-1234-1")
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim Res As String

For Each el In arr1
    arr2 = Split(el, "-")
    Debug.Print Join(Array(Format(arr2(0), "00000"), Format(arr2(1), "0000"), Format(arr2(2), "0000")), "-")
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Uggh good eyes, I didn't even see that dropped digit. Maybe a typo?

Comment: Revised original typo in post.